# Does MFCreateAggregateSource make any guarantees about ordering?

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

If I create an aggregate media source in Windows Media Foundation using `MFCreateAggregateSource`, are the streams ordered in the same order as the sources in the collection passed to `MFCreateAggregateSource`? If not, is there any way to determine which actual source creates which stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doubts could be cleared out by MSDN article for [`MFCreateAggregateSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388085) explaining the order of aggregation, but it does not provide such details (at the moment).

Those having experience with the API report that aggregation order is straightforward: the order of collection elements, and streams within individual sources.

See more in cross-post on [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6148b07b-d5ce-48e7-a8fd-fe6a35014e49/order-of-streams-in-source-created-using-mfcreateaggregatesource?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment):

> Example 1 :
>
> You have 3 Media Sources, A, B and C. Each source has only one stream.
>   If you add them in alphabetical order to a collection, you will get 3
>   streams on the Aggregate Source.
>
> ->
>
> Stream 0 is Source A ( Stream 0 )
>
> Stream 1 is Source B ( Stream 0 )
>
> Stream 2 is Source C ( Stream 0 )
>
> Example 2 :
>
> Same Media Sources, but this time B has 2 streams. If you add the
>   sources in alphabetical order to a collection, you will get 4 streams
>   on the Aggregate Source.
>
> ->
>
> Stream 0 is Source A ( Stream 0 )
>
> Stream 1 is Source B ( Stream 0 )
>
> Stream 2 is Source B ( Stream 1 )
>
> Stream 3 is Source C ( Stream 0 )